# HashMap with int array (int[]) as value returns null on get?

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

I have a Hashmap that stores a student name as the key and an int array of scores as the value. I know its creating the HashMap correctly but when trying to return the int array for a key I cant seem to get.

```
public int[] getQuizzes(String studentName)
    {
        int[] studentsQuizzes = quizMarks.get(studentName);
        return studentsQuizzes; 
    }
```

It just ends up returning null. What am I missing, thanks for any help

This is how I am creating the hashmap

```
quizMarks = new HashMap<String, int[]>();   

public void addStudent(String studentName)
    {
        String formattedName = formatName(studentName);
        int[] quizzes = new int[NUM_QUIZZES];
        for (int i = 0; i < quizzes.length; i++)
        {
            quizzes[i] = MIN_GRADE;
        }
        quizMarks.put(formattedName, quizzes);
    }
```

Comment: can we see your code for populating it? I see nothing wrong with this

Comment: How do you "know its creating the hashmap correctly" if you can't get anything from it?

Comment: Not enough information to answer. What data **is** contained in the hashmap? Are you sure it contains the key for whatever value of `studentName` you're passing in? (how are you sure?)

Comment: Print out the 'quizMarks' to check what are in the Map.

Comment: I would guess that there's no key matching studentName in your HashMap, or else the value stored with that key is null.  You can tell which with containsKey.

Comment: Write a small, self-contained application (a console app is a good choice) that demonstrates inserting and attempting to retrieve data. There's a good chance you'll find the problem while doing that. Otherwise, post that (short!) program here.

Comment: As Shengyaun suggests, `System.out.println(quizMarks.toString());` would be revealing.

Comment: `{Bob=[I@4c67e5a7}`
Is what is printed. When I debug it I can follow the key to the value which is a int array filled with 10 values of 0. So its creating it ok, at least I think. thanks for all the help so far.

Comment: The issue is too specialized. It is a bug in the program. Does this sort of thing belong on Code Review?

Comment: you must match the student name *exactly*. The only clue is that you `put` something you call a `formattedName` but your `getQuizzes` method tried to use something called `studentName` as the key. Perhaps you need to call your `formatName` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your keys in the map are the results of calling `formatName` on the student name passed in. You don't appear to be using the formatted name as the key when calling `get` on the map, meaning the keys you pass to `get` are not the same as those you passed to `put`.

Comment: Yup, totally right. formatName was capitalizing it and I completely missed that. Thanks!